# Socket.send on the server on page request

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible for the server to do a socket.send on page request?

so it any client that request a certain page the server side can send a post message to all clients.

so when a web request comes into a page called "status". i want the server code to parse the querystring and broadcast, but i'm unable to get the io object in my app.js to do so.

```
  var url = require('url');


exports.update = function(req, res){
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;

    // here i want to broadcast the query string query.update     

    res.render('status', { status: query.update });
};
```

Comment: of course it is, show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  io.sockets.emit('your event name', {data: 'some data'});
});
```

Comment: I love this amazing tools :)